# Stops or dashes for pauses in dialogue

Tags: punctuation

What is the correct punctuation when one wants to include breaks or pauses in dialogue? Sometimes I use stops. For example,

> "It is possible...I...could be wrong."

I have heard this is wrong and dashes are correct. If so, is it an en-dash or an em-dash? I must say stops--to me--look better on the page.

Comment: Ellipses come in threes. Period?  Just one, if you please.

Answer (score 2):

Punctuation is a matter of style, and as such, you should be guided by your manual of style.  The rules differ between such manuals, and if you're lucky enough to write for yourself without the watchful eye of editors and professors, then you may establish and use your own rules.  Which should at least be consistent to be kind to your readers.

That said, I prefer the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which discusses what you're describing under the name *faltering speech*.  If you are reporting speech marked by "confusion, insecurity, distress, or uncertainty", *CMS* recommends ellipses.  On the other hand, if your speech represents some decisiveness, the *CMS* recommends one or two em-dashes (also called simply *dashes*) for "interruptions, abrupt changes in thought, or impatient fractures of grammar."

Thus

> It is possible . . . I . . . could be wrong

represents the thoughts of someone who's unsure of his facts, while

> It is possible--though I'd claim highly unlikely--that I could be wrong

represents the thoughts of someone who thinks the possibility that he's wrong is remote.

Note that *CMS* likes spaces around the periods in an ellipsis, but none around the dashes.

Answer (score 0):

The choice is literary and/or typographical, since statements such as the one cited in the example represent broken speech, and not (usually) well-tempered grammatical sentences.

> "It is possible...I...could be wrong."

Readers will construe the as hesitant, and may attempt to populate the pauses indicated by the ellipsis (the three stop-characters) with imagined thoughts, reflections, recriminations or physical actions on the part of the speaker.

Pauses in speech may also be indicated by a em-dash, although the preference of many typesetters *seems* to favor ellipsis.